git add . stuck for a long time

I was performing git add . for one of my projects. The project is tiny and I have also put node_modules in .gitignore. I tried the same command in different projects, and it was working fine. For this one, it has been stuck for a long time. I have attached the image above.

This is my .gitignore file.

I'm getting this while trying to git add one of the files from red area.

what is in your .gitignore? it could be adding all the nodejs dependencies

I want to know how I can perform the git add . in the same project.

Nothing specified, nothing added.
hint: Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addEmptyPathspec false" --- I'm getting this when I use git add

I just used git add, I tried the same command for one or two files. It was working fine, but don't know why git add . is getting stucked.

Why do you try to add .parcel-cache to your repository if you have included it in .gitignore?

It's showing in Changes not staged for commit. Does the files present in .gitignore shows here ?

Yes, if it was added to the repository before. Do you want .parcel-cache in your repository? I guess not.

I don't need it now, what shall I do ?

Are you working on a network or shared drive?

Files in .parcel_cache, node_modules, and dist are marked as "modified" meaning they have already been tracked by Git (the first git add on a file will cause it to be tracked) and committed. .gitignore only works to prevent files from being tracked.
These directories can be very large. When you git add them, Git has to copy their contents. If you're on a slow disk or a network drive this can take quite some time.
First, remove any staged changes to those files with git restore --staged. Then remove those files from the next commit with git rm --cached while retaining the files on disk. Commit that. The result should be that .parcel_cache, node_modules, and dist are no longer tracked by the repository.
